# Find the frequency of each word at the sentence level

Tags: python, text, frequency

I have a text file of a text whose words were part-of-speech tagged. The file can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dbIkiLiRmWM1hLeSI_v-ajxX1msSYbFr/view?usp=sharing%60). So, each word and its tags are in one line. Sentences are divided by the tag SPACE. I'm trying to create a program that 1) find words with frequency above 1 containing tags NOUN, VERB, ADJ and ADV at the sentence level 2) prints the sum of the frequencies found. The program I've created is calculating the frequency incorrectly because it is adding the frequency of the same words in the previous sentences. This is not what I want. I want to calculate the frequency of the item (words and tags) in each sentence without accumulating the frequencies of the previous sentences. Can anyone help me with this task?
my code so far is below:

```
while True:
    try:
        file_to_open =Path("Please, insert your file path: "))
        with open(file_to_open,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            sentences = f.read()
            break   
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\nFile not found. Better try again")
    except IsADirectoryError:
        print("\nIncorrect Directory path.Try again")


units=sentences.split('<<SPACE>>')    


print(len(units))
count={}

w=open('Alice_repetitions_sentence_AnaB.txt','w')
for sentence_num, unit in enumerate(units, 1):
    lines=unit.split('\n')
    total_count=len(lines)
    for s in lines:
        if s in count:
            count[s]+=1
     
        else:
            count[s]=1
for key in count:

    if 'VERB' in key and count[key] >1:
        print(sentence_num,key, count[key])
    elif 'NOUN' in key and count[key] >1:
        print(sentence_num,key, count[key])
    elif 'ADJ' in key and count[key] >1:
        print(sentence_num,key, count[key])
    elif 'ADV' in key and count[key] >1:
        print(sentence_num,key, count[key])
```

My desired output should be:

sentence 1: word1 - 4, word2 - 3, word3 - 8, so on..repeated items: 3

sentence 2: word1 - 4, word2 - 3, word3 - 8, word4-10 so on..repeated items: 4.

sentence 3: word1 - 4, word2 - 3, word3 - 8, word4-10, word5-15 so on..repeated items: 5.

Comment: Write a function that will determine and return your *frequencies* for any string that it is passed then just pass *sentences* to the function and accumulate the return values.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
def word_count(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
            return Counter(f.read().split())

print("Number of words in the file :",word_count("test.txt"))
```

simplified version to count frequency of word

Comment: I want to count the frequency of words for each sentence separately.

Comment: Do you have any own unique indication to identify the sentences?

Comment: yes, as I said in the explanation of my problem. Sentences are separated in the file by tag <<SPACE>>. This was added to my code. sentences.split('<<SPACE>>')